# Display last imported week

Tags: vba, excel, week-number

I have a **excel file that imports from weekly files**. I can **specify the number of week to import in an input box**. From this number, I construct the file path and name for that specific week and then imports it.

**In cell D1 I want to show the week that was last imported**, so if I last Imported week 12, cell D1 should show "12" and if later later I imported a file from a older week like 4, cell D1 should show "4"

In the excel file the source files that will be imported will be trough a vba code, it don't have any type of tables in the source file, so I need to implement this in my code in order to show in the cell D1 the week that as been imported.

I tried implementing this to my code `Range("D1").Value = WeekVal` in order to try to fill that specific cell with the number of the week that was imported.

I searched online but the ones that I saw didn't apply very well to my code. So I don't really need a date **I just need the value from the file name** that represents the week, like here :

> "Status 496 800 week -->**12**<-- 2015.xls"

that number is what I need to show in the D1

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: I tried this without success   Range("D1").Value = WeekVal, sorry forgot that I changed the name, but still doesn't work

Comment: is the activesheet the correct sheet and what values are in wk?

Comment: Well in "WeekVal" it needs to be the week value or the current week where the file was made. I think it is because it imports the necessary information.

Comment: edit your question to contain all the relevant information, including the formulas you tried, the problems you found with detailed information.

Comment: So I don't want to take a specific week it's just to take the number of the week in the file, they are named like this depending on the week = "Status 496 800 week 12 2015" so I just want that number 12 that is the week.

Comment: Do you have try some code already? (if so, please edit your question to include it). It'll be so much easier to have a working base, because your question isn't hard but without some basis, it is far tougher!

Comment: @R3uK, I think this is not a duplicate from what you refer. The week number here is just a suffix (or infix) of the file name or file path.

Comment: @DirkHorsten : Yup, I saw that afterwards but didn't know how to unflag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your file's name is referenced so I did a function, here is a routine to test it :

```
Sub Luis_Montez()
Dim TpS As String, _
    ReZ As String

TpS = "Status 496 800 week 12 2015"
ReZ = Get_WeekNb_From_FileName(TpS)

MsgBox "_" & ReZ & "_"
End Sub
```

And here is the function :

```
Public Function Get_WeekNb_From_FileName(ByVal FileName As String) As Integer
Dim TpStr As String
    TpStr = Trim(Mid(FileName, InStr(1, LCase(FileName), "week") + 4, 3))
Get_WeekNb_From_FileName = CInt(TpStr)
End Function
```

---

An even easier solution that in the duplicate, just use :

```
Format(Date, "ww")
```

Comment: this will make what? because I want to see the week of the file because every file that is imported to my file have a specific week

Answer (score 0):

You are probably writing your WeekVal in the D2 cell of another worksheet (for instance the workbook you just imported your data for the week from).

To avoid this, **always refer to any cell or range by explicitly naming the workbook and either the named range or the sheet name**.

In your case, I advice to select the D1-cell you want to write to. Now left of your formula bar you can read `D1`. Fill in `WeekVal` instead. Then change your code to

```
Thisworkbook.Name("WeekVal").RefersToRange.Value = WeekVal
```